# Изъять текст ссылки из тэга ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

В js функцию поступает текст со ссылкой:
`<a href="blabla" target="_blank">http://site.ru/</a>`.

Как можно форматировать этот текст, чтобы от ссылки осталось только то, что идёт между тэгами `<a>`?

То есть, получаем такой текст:

> hello, http:site.ru

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`String::match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
let text = '<a href="blabla" target_blank">http://site.ru/</a>';
let link = text.match(/a href=".*">(.*)<\/a>/)[1];
console.log(link);
```

Comment: мне кажется не совсем то..
вообщем мы получаем такой текст: текст 123 <a>'http://lol'</a> 
и нужно чтобы ссылка в итоге вернула такой текст: текст 123 'http://lol'

Comment: @turik97 Если задача отличается от сформулированной в вопросе, попросите Кирилла отредактировать вопрос.